# How to Construct a value block on MifareClassic via Android NFC API

Tags: android, nfc, mifare

My question is that the Android NFC API has already provided "increment" and "decrement" a value block , but if I have a new MifareClassic Tag(it's not have any value block inside), how can i use the Android NFC API to construct a value block on this new tag ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just write properly formatted data to the tag. See section 8.6.2 of the [MIFARE Classic datasheet](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/MF1S50YYX.pdf) for an example.

Example Android code to store an integer `value` as value block in block `blockIndex`:

```
// connect to the tag using a Tag object from an NFC intent
MifareClassic mifare = MifareClassic.get(tag);
mifare.connect();

// need to authenticate first to get access
int sector = blockToSector(blockIndex);
mifare.authenticateSectorWithKeyA(sector, keyA); // you need to know key A
// mifare.authenticateSectorWithKeyB(sector, keyB); // in case you know key B

// construct value block of value zero; "address" byte is set to 0 in this example
byte[] zeroValue = {0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 255 };
mifare.writeBlock(blockIndex, zeroValue);

// increase the value block by some amount
mifare.increment(blockIndex, value);
// result is stored in scratch register inside tag; now write result to block
mifare.transfer(blockIndex);
```

Keep in mind that the access control bits for the block need to be set correctly to allow the increment operation for the key you use to authenticate.

Comment: Thank you very much!! It's really work! sorry so late to receive you.

Comment: I have only writeBlock and not write...is it normal?